# How to display road name in marker infowindow while displaying route in google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I need road name in marker infowindow while displaying route in google maps.

I found the following options,
 1. Geocoder service in Google Maps Javascript API - which will give address for the given GPS coordinate.
 2. Google Maps Roads API - which will return placeIds of the path and again I need to fire another request to get the address of placeId

What will be optimal solution to retrieve the road name for a given route (array of gps coordinates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) is the appropriate API to use for converting lat/lng coordinates into textual addresses and vice-versa. It's what it's meant to be used for.

The following is an example of a reverse geocoding request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this api gives address for only one coordinate. Is there any other better option to obtain road name for array for gps coordinates ?

Comment: no, you cannot reverse geocode multiple gps coordinates in a single query with the Geocoding API (or any other Maps API). But you may want to batch geocode them using the client libraries https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library